# Eclipse Tomcat loading old data

Tags: eclipse, spring, jsp, tomcat7

Eclipse loads on tomcat7 old spring data, I tried deleteing project in .metadata , add new server and Eclipse still shows old webapp. Anyone knows how to solve this problem ?

Answer (score 0):

try deleting /target/ (if you use maven, try mvn clean install).

Answer (score 0):

When you work in integrated Eclipse/Tomcat environment and make changes to your code, re-starting Tomcat to reflect the change is the best solution.

In your case I would also try to clean/build the project again, so here are steps that you might want to take:

1. Clean the project
2. Build
3. Re-start Tomcat